# Как в документации bitcoinpay получают из ответа сервера хэш?

Tags: python, хеширование, платежи, bitcoin

Делаю прием платежей через bitcoinpay.com
В документации столкнулся с примером проверки платежа. Прежде чем использовать этот способ у себя решил проделать описанное в примере. И как не старался, никак не выходит у меня получить тот же хэш, что получается у них.
Вот [пример из документации](http://docs.bitcoinpaycom.apiary.io/#introduction/callback-password). Но приведу его и здесь.
Пример ответа от сервера:

```
{"data": {"status": "pending", "payment_id": "rvnEvs3pzGVlBQaE", "settled_currency": "USD", "server_time": 1438681512, "paid_amount": "0.03545288", "reference": "{\"customer_email\": \"john.doe@example.org\", \"order_number\": 1234, \"customer_name\": \"John Doe\"}", "payment_url": "https://bitcoinpay.com/en/sci/invoice/btc/rvnEvs3pzGVlBQaE/", "price": "10.00", "confirmations": -1, "settled_amount": "6.95", "txid": "", "currency": "USD", "create_time": 1438688711, "item": "Order #1234", "address": "172eh5xbTW9Fu4EvaNZt1ymoUz9pV2snYG", "timeout_time": 1438689611, "paid_currency": "BTC", "description": "Order #1234 description"}}
```

Известно что callback password он же я так понимаю api key - `QKG7m{dzv32mmYGN`

хэш вычисляют из строки вида <ответ><пароль>
и получают хэш `3ee96c641d5fe230343950839aff469fa7c79b52bfefc5790bb9308ddeab605a`

я приводил всё к строке ну и дальше вычислял хэш, пробовал и целиком и так

```
j = {"data": {.....}}
d = j["data"]
```

Потом мне попалась [другая документация](https://bitcoinpay.com/api/v1/) с того же сайта, где хэш высчитывали уже именно не с ответа целиком, а с секции дата, причем значения были отсортированы по ключам в алфавитном порядке. Попробовал сделать также для примера выше.

```
import hashlib

d = {"status": "pending", "payment_id": "rvnEvs3pzGVlBQaE", "settled_currency": "USD", "server_time": 1438681512, "paid_amount": "0.03545288", "reference": "{\"customer_email\": \"john.doe@example.org\", \"order_number\": 1234, \"customer_name\": \"John Doe\"}", "payment_url": "https://bitcoinpay.com/en/sci/invoice/btc/rvnEvs3pzGVlBQaE/", "price": "10.00", "confirmations": -1, "settled_amount": "6.95", "txid": "", "currency": "USD", "create_time": 1438688711, "item": "Order #1234", "address": "172eh5xbTW9Fu4EvaNZt1ymoUz9pV2snYG", "timeout_time": 1438689611, "paid_currency": "BTC", "description": "Order #1234 description"}
a = "QKG7m{dzv32mmYGN"

s = ""
l = d.keys()
l.sort()
for c in l:
    s+=str(d[c])

s +=a
h = hashlib.sha256(s).hexdigest()
print h
```

Хэш всё-равно не совпал. 
Подскажите как они высчитали этот хэш в первом примере? А то я теряюсь в догадках как считать его у себя. Вроде и написано что строка из whole data + callback password, но на деле получается не так. Может уже кто-то реализовал на python? Был бы рад увидеть примеры.

P.S. попадался готовый пример из модуля к какой-то cms, там это выглядело что-то вроде этого:

```
hash('sha256', '$RESPONSE_HTTP' . '$CALLBACK_PASSWORD')
```

Я не знаком с PHP, но думаю что тут происходит конкатенация ответа c паролем и вычисление хеша.

P.P.S. Попробовал на живом примере(листинг ниже) посчитать. Что по первому, что по второму способу, хэши не сошлись.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#--*--coding: utf-8--*--

import json
import hashlib
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen

pwd = "мой_callback_password"

login = "zxcv432fg"
email = "zxc@dfg.ru"
satoshi = 0.001
values = {
    "settled_currency": "BTC",
    "return_url": "http://site.ru/buy/thankyou.html",
    "notify_url": "http://site.ru/cgi-bin/btc/order-received.cgi",
    "notify_email": "mail@mail.ru",
    "price": satoshi,
    "currency": "BTC",
    "reference": {
      "customer_name": login,
      "order_number": 123,
      "customer_email": email
    },
    "item": "la2coin",
    "description": "buy la2coin"
  }

data = json.dumps(values)
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': 'Token мой_ключ_апи'
}
request = Request('https://www.bitcoinpay.com/api/v1/payment/btc',
                     data=data, headers=headers)

response = urlopen(request)
response_body = urlopen(request).read()

signature = response.info()['BPSignature']
data_validate = response_body + pwd

hash_string = hashlib.sha256(data_validate).hexdigest()

print "ответ - ", response_body, '\n'
print "строка для хеширования - ", data_validate, '\n'
print "Хеш с заголовка - ", signature, '\n'
print "Рассчитаный хеш - ", hash_string, '\n'

if signature == hash_string:
    print "Validated succesfully!"
else:
    print "Wrong Signature"
```

Comment: обращался в саппорт, но ответ не получил

Comment: _я приводил всё к строке ну и дальше вычислял хэш_, покажите как к строке приводили. в документации сказано взять ответ с сервера в виде строки, значит `j={...}` точно не годится. не знаю как в питоне, но если там текст можно заключать в одинарные кавычки, то я бы сделал типа `a='{"data": {"status": "pending", ...` т.е. со всеми пробелами как у них. ну или как то экранировать кавычки что бы в строку один к одному их заанести

Comment: а зачем вы считаете хеш для ответа сервера? По идее такая технология используется для отправки запросов. Т.е. сформировали запрос, посчитали для него хеш и указали в запросе - чтобы сервер мог проверить что по дороге ничего не "потерялось"

Comment: @newman В платежных системах принято так же проверять ответы серверов. потому как они не ответы, а запросы. сервер процессинга при прохождении платежа вызывает http callback адрес, т.е. скрипт на стороне клиента и сообщает о платеже. вот тут его и надо проверять, что бы злоумышленник не послал свой запрос о якобы пришедших деньгах

Comment: прошу, переименуйте заголовок вопроса. по заголовку не понятен смысл вопроса.

Comment: @Mike, согласен. Тогда собственно к автору вопроса одна просьба - добавьте в вопрос тот самый хеш, который пришел с указанными данными от сервиса - чтобы было проще определить как оно считают.

Comment: @Mike, строку формировал так: 
`a = """ {data: {тут инфа с запроса которую копировал из примера по первой ссылке}}QKG7m{dzv32mmYGN"""`

Comment: А вывод скрипта с "живым" примером можно увидеть?

Comment: @newman [ссылка на картинку с выводом](http://img10.lostpic.net/2016/02/18/846158ffe512ab1c232943b14e71b237.png)

Comment: @SergeyWhite понятно. Попробуйте формировать строку, другим способом - как конкатенацию значений для определенных ключей - как это показано в https://bitcoinpay.com/api/v1/

Comment: @newman, так тоже уже пробовал. не совпадают.

Comment: @newman получил ответ от техподдержки. Отправлял им мой код. Пишут долго тестировали. Удивляются почему не работает. Пришли к выводу, что Requests что-то изменяет в входящих и исходящих запросах. попробовали написать используя request вместо urllib2. В итоге получилось. Сказали что займутся этим вопросом. Так что проблема исчерпана. Сейчас попробовал. Всё получилось. Кому интересно, решение тут http://pastebin.com/5nTPeX6u

Answer (score 1):

Пока что нашел одно возможное место для возникновения "ошибки" - некорректнный расчет хеша

А именно поле description. В приведенном примере данных оно есть, а значит и его значение попадает в строку для расчета хеш. В документации такое поле не упоминается.

Я бы для пробы не формировал массив ключей исходя из полученного ответа, как это сделано у вас `l = d.keys()`, а формировал бы его вручную в коде, как список полей, которые должны принимать участие в расчета хеша. Заодно можно дополнительно проверять, что от сервиса были полученны все нужные поля.

UPDATE:
По ссылке https://bitcoinpay.com/api/v1/

В Питоне не силен, поэтому делал на PHP (кстати, приведенный в вопросе пример некорректен. Не знает PHP про алгоритм хеширования hash256)

```
 <?php
 $str = '1ADeusgHpfeB5wY3YbgCZty4zdxMF9BcLE31399569216EUR0.12231BTCtE8ZHEqEzJWUCGSDhttps://bitcoinpay.com/sci/invoice/btc/tE8ZHEqEzJWUCGSD/17.5{"customer_email": "customer@example.com", "order_number": 123, "customer_name": "Customer Name"}139956267417.31EURconfirmed1399569276f1be3a5df76864e3b7b13ded87ceac1d5c10887af6f7b1f1541f208f10d970daxxx';

 echo(hash('sha256', $str)."\n");
 ?>
```

В результате получаю

```
88fe519e4fae530df49b566d2b493a8f3836d51d2b9cf656ff4859ad9920656b
```

Это совпадает со значением поля `secret.callback_password_hash`

Т.е. можно предположить, что в документации есть ошибки и указанный там хеш `bea ... e25` некорректен. Вероятней всего остался от какого-то редактирования.

Ну и в любом случае надо пробовать на живо сайте - документация не всегда бывает на 100% правильной и корректной.

Comment: в документации по первой приведенной мной ссылке есть поле description. считаю именно тот пример. массив ключей формирую для того, чтобы отсортировать в алфавитном порядке ключи и взять их value (чтобы подвести к примеру из второй ссылки).

Comment: Я бы все же опирался бы на вторую ссылку. Это все же информация с самого сайт, а не со стороннего ресурса. Хотя у них там тоже ошибка. В самой документации хеш указан неправильно, а вот в примере данных корректно.

Comment: @SergeyWhite, Дополнил ответ.

Comment: со второй ссылкой получилось. И да, тоже обратил внимание, что правильный только в поле secret. сейчас проверил на живом примере. что первый вариант(в первом варианте, кстати ответ это уже и есть строка, преобразовывать не надо), что второй. хэши не совпали. к тому же в ответе поля secret не увидел. Сейчас код добавлю в вопрос, где смотрел.